# Obtener Id en específico

Tags: javascript

Necesito seleccionar un ID con `let closeProduct = document.getElementById("closeProduct")` PERO este ID es único ya que se recorre desde un array y se le asignó su id.  Pero cuando hago `console.log` me sale `null`... ¿Fallé en algo o qué me hace falta?  Lo necesito así ya que necesito recorrer otro array para hacer una comparación y seleccionar con el id ese mismo producto para eliminarlo más adelante.

```
  let dato = `itemProduct${productId}`
  let closeProductGo = document.getElementById(dato).value

    const htmlArrayProducts = arraymaster.filter((elem) => elem[`Fórmula Médica`]?.[0] === "Si").map(({ productName, productId, items }) => (
    `<div class="containerProduct" id="itemProduct${productId}" key="${productId}">
      <div class="productGroup">
        <img src="${items[0].images[0].imageUrl}" alt="${productName}" class="imageUrlProduct" />
        <span>${productName}</span>
      </div>
    <button type="button" class="closeProduct" id="closeProduct${productId}">X</button>
  </div>`
  ))

    arraymaster.map((item) => {
    console.log("item", item)
    console.log("itemProduct", item.productId)
    console.log("closeProductGo2", closeProductGo)
      if(item.productId === closeProductGo){
        itemIdToRemove.push({ index: item.productId, quantity: 0 })
      }
    })
```

Comment: Parece que dato tiene el valor de itemProduct${productId} cuando deberia ser closeProduct${productId}